# execute_process and add_custom_target behave differently with respect to COMMAND

Tags: matlab, cmake, process, execute

have a strange issue, I need to run matlab script and use the generated code for compilation.
I would like to run matlab2018b(64 bit) in Windows  without display and I am using MinGW as makefile generator.
For me this works without the display but is not intended (I need generation before build)

```
add_custom_target(generate_sources ALL COMMAND ${Matlab_MAIN_PROGRAM} -nosplash -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -minimize -wait -log -r "matlab_script"
```

While this works with matlab display:

```
execute_process(
COMMAND           "${Matlab_MAIN_PROGRAM}"  -nosplash -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -minimize -wait -log -r "matlab_script"
ERROR_VARIABLE    STDERR
RESULT_VARIABLE   RES
TIMEOUT           600
INPUT_FILE        NUL
COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)
message("OUTPUT variable is: ${RES}")
if(NOT (RES EQUAL 0) OR STDERR MATCHES "\?\?\? Error")
message( FATAL_ERROR "execute_process returned ${RES}" )
endif()
```

I would like to use execute_process as it is meant during config time.
I suspect there is something in the way that I specify COMMAND in both cases.
Could someone please help?

Comment: “I am using MinGW as makefile generator.” Do you mean CMake? MinGW is not a makefile generator.

Comment: What do you mean by “display”? What is the problem?

Comment: “I need to run matlab script and use the generated code for compilation.” and “I would like to use execute_process as it is meant during config time.” are mutually contradictory statements. If you need the output for compilation, it’s a build-time dependency. If you need the results to define how stuff is built, then it’s a configuration-time job.

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific enough. I do use cmake and mingw as makefile generator. What I need is pre-build step. Therefore, I would like to use execute_process . When I use add_custom_target it works but after build. add_custom_command can be used only at PRE_LINK step. This is not useful for my use-case. I need a PRE_BUILD step.